# Remove item in array recursive call pattern?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

When dealing with a recursive call within an array object, where I'm passing an array to a function and each proceeding call, I'd like the array argument to be n-1.

I normally use:

- Array.prototype.shift
- Array.prototype.pop

I have to call these methods the line before the recursive call.  Check the example below.

Here is what I normally resort to:

```
function responseData(urls){
    if (urls.length-1){
        return;
    }
    http.get(urls[0], function(res) {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      var body = '';
      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function() {
            console.log(body.toString());
            urls.shift(); // NOTICE THIS LINE
            printResponseData(urls);
      });
    });
}
```

Is there a cleaner alternative to this approach?

Can I eliminate using `shift` or `pop` that return values, to a method that will minimize the size of the array and return the newly minified array so I can pass this straight to my recursive call?

Comment: `printResponseData(urls.slice(1));`

Comment: `if (urls.length-1){` is weird. Did you mean `if (urls.length==0){`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`slice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a smaller array. It won't mutate the original argument, but rather create a new one.

To get an array without the first element, use

```
urls.slice(1)
```

To get an array without the last element, use

```
urls.slice(0, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is what you mean?

```
printResponseData(urls.slice(1));
```

will skip the first element and give the rest to the end of the array

```
// or
printResponseData(urls.slice(0, -1));
```

will give from the start of the array to the penultimate element.

Comment: Just like what Bergi said!